# Pytest fixture command line returning function object instead of value

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures, conftest

I am trying to take a command line input for testing.
Instead of returning the input as a string, python fixture is returning a function object

My contest.py file has this code:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--n', action='store', default='mark', help='user name')
    parser.addoption('--pwd', action='store', default='pwd', help='password')


@pytest.fixture
def get_name(request) -> str:
    return request.config.getoption('--n')

@pytest.fixture
def get_pwd(request) -> str:
    return request.config.getoption('--pwd')
```

and my example test is:

```
def test_names():
    print(get_name)
    assert get_name == 'mark'
    

def test_pwd():
    print(get_pwd)
    assert get_pwd == 'p'
```

The return is an error and when I try to print `get_pwd` and `get_name`, it prints:

`<function get_name at 0x7f8431fcdc10> <function get_pwd at 0x7f8431fcda60>`

I have used same code before and it has returned the input value but here it is returning function object.

my command line input is:

```
pytest -s test.py --n=mark --pwd=p
```

How can I get it to return the command line input instead of the function object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the `fixture` as a test parameter

```
def test_names(get_name):
    print(get_name)
    assert get_name == 'mark'


def test_pwd(get_pwd):
    print(get_pwd)
    assert get_pwd == 'p'
```

Output

```
test.py::test_names PASSED                                               [ 50%]mark

test.py::test_pwd PASSED                                                 [100%]p
```